# Launching Activity With FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

When an activity is launched with the Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP from an activity doing some important background work using AsyncTask. What happens to background task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background task will be continue processed.

From docs :

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

*How works AsyncTask?
Let's see AsyncTask source:*

```
/**
     * Creates a new asynchronous task. This constructor must be invoked on the UI thread.
     */
    public AsyncTask() {
        mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
            public Result call() throws Exception {
                mTaskInvoked.set(true);

                Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                //noinspection unchecked
                Result result = doInBackground(mParams);
                Binder.flushPendingCommands();
                return postResult(result);
            }
        };

        mFuture = new FutureTask<Result>(mWorker) {
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    postResultIfNotInvoked(get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    android.util.Log.w(LOG_TAG, e);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("An error occurred while executing doInBackground()",
                            e.getCause());
                } catch (CancellationException e) {
                    postResultIfNotInvoked(null);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

We need only two things, that need to be keep in mind.

- WorkerRunnable is actually Callable
- Result result = doInBackground(mParams); // processed in background thread

So here it is your answer. `doInBackground` will be processed, but `onPostExecute` might be produced NPE, because parent activity was destroyed.